# How to set a timeout on stanford nlp parsing

Tags: stanford-nlp

Hi i am using the pipeline object to parse forums posts. for each one i do the following :

```
Annotation document = new Annotation(post);
mPipeline.annotate(document);       // annoatiate the post text
```

I would like each call to annotate to timeout after a few seconds.
I have followed the example at line 65: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/itest/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotatorITest.java

So i am creating the pipeline object as follows :

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("parse.maxtime", "30");
    props.setProperty("dcoref.maxtime", "30");
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    mPipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

How ever when i add the maxtime properties i get the following exception :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentenceAnnotator.annotate(SentenceAnnotator.java:64)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:68)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:412)

Without the maxtime option there is no exception.

how can i set maxtime properly ?

Thanks

Comment: I recreated your error, and this appears to be a bug in the time out functionality.  One thing that might help is to use parse.maxlen as an alternative and skip especially long sentences.  I will try to investigate further what is causing this bug.  Thanks for bringing this issue up!

Comment: You could always just use a separate thread, and set a timeout on it, then interrupt the processing if it hasn't finished by some time (millisToWait): Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { mPipeline.annotate(document); }}; th.start(); th.join(millisToWait); if(th.isAlive()) { th.interrupt(); }